# Coudn't connect to docker hbase from local IDE

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, docker-compose, hbase

I have a docker machine with ip 10.101.48.150.
Where is my standalone hbase using next docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: namenode
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    networks:
      hbasenetwork:
        aliases:
            - namenode
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: datanode
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    networks:
      hbasenetwork:
        aliases:
            - datanode
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    networks:
      hbasenetwork:
        aliases:
            - resourcemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:latest
    container_name: nodemanager
    networks:
      hbasenetwork:
        aliases:
            - nodemanager1
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline.
    networks:
      hbasenetwork:
        aliases:
            - historyserver
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  hbase:
    image: bde2020/hbase-standalone:latest
    container_name: hbase
    volumes:
      - hbase_data:/hbase-data
      - hbase_zookeeper_data:/zookeeper-data
    ports:
      - 16000:16000
      - 16010:16010
      - 16020:16020
      - 16030:16030
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
      - 2182:2181
    hostname: hbase
    networks:
      hbasenetwork:
        aliases:
            - hbase
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075"
    env_file:
      - ./hbase-standalone.env

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
  hbase_data:
  hbase_zookeeper_data:
networks:
  hbasenetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

My java code:

```
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
```

My config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>10.101.48.150</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2182</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

When i tried to work with it from my java, i see next message:

```
running.java.net.UnknownHostException: hbase
```

I understand what my java ask for something from docker hbase container using 10.101.48.150:2082, response smt and get back address as a "hbase", my local network don't know anything about any "hbase" and fault. I tried add to hosts file a line 10.101.48.150 hbase, but then i see next error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

I don't understand how to connect my local IDE with Hbase container.

Comment: `hbase` is a name resovable in the docker netowrk only. You can add it to your /etc/hosts file on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

On your `hbase` service in docker-compose you did map those port:

```
ports:
  - 16000:16000
  - 16010:16010
  - 16020:16020
  - 16030:16030
  - 2888:2888
  - 3888:3888
  - 2182:2181
```

There is no port mapping for port 2082, so your application cannot successfully connect to it.

Comment: Whats for 2082 port needed? Couldn't find it in doc.

Comment: Perhaps you miss a copy paste. I assume on your question that your error was referencing port 2082. If not then I guess the issue is the mapping 2182:2181. Hbase diffuse the name hbase and port 2181 but you set a mapping 2182 on the docker machine.